# How to use setup JSON file for use in another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, xcode, api

I would just like to ask. How I can setup my JSON file for use? Like I created a taskList.json file in javascript, however, I don't know what are the next steps to parsing the data. The code I have is below:

```
{
    "project": "temp",
    "tasks": [{
        "_id": "5",
        "view_id": "5bcf473",
        "projectname": "5bcf4628b68cb41182c1f5db",
        "task_name": "add security",
        "view_index": 1,
        "created_by": {
            "created_by_ref": "ai",
            "created_by_name": "Benni",
            "created_by_avi": "benn@gmail.com"
        },
        "assiged_to": {
            "assiged_name": "Benni",
            "assiged_ref": "sddhf2ef",
            "role": "developer"
        },
        "planned": {
            "started": 0,
            "end": 0
        },
        "Smartys": [{
            "words": "detail",
            "task": "planned_estimated_time",
            "secret": "task_details",
            "date": 0
        }]
    }]

}
```

Comment: Are you using NodeJS or is it regular browser-JS?

Comment: I will use node js

Comment: Also, does the file extension matter? It becomes a bit easier if it is a `.js` file instead of `.json`

Comment: I can change the file extension, but how do I go about extracting the data to other files?

Comment: In that case, if you rename the file to .js and prepend a `module.exports = ` to your JSON object, you can simply import it into your main script by using `const xy = require('./path/to/the/file.js');`. Then you can access it by using `xy.project`.

Comment: Of course you can change the `xy` to something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply require the file

```
var json = require('./taskList.json');
```

and node will parse it for you.